# javascript arguments passed as objects instead of strings

Tags: javascript, function, arguments

Please help me understand how this could happen: I think I'm passing simple strings to a Javascript function, but they are received as form objects! The first argument is the `id` of the form. The second argument is the `name` of an input.

```
var div = document.getElementById('demo');
var elCheckbox = document.createElement('input');
var myFormId = 'hi', myInputName = 'bye';

console.log(typeof myFormId);       // logs: string
console.log(typeof myInputName);    // logs: string

elCheckbox.setAttribute('onclick','toggleHideField(' + myFormId + ', ' + myInputName + ');');
document.getElementById('hi').appendChild(elCheckbox);

function toggleHideField(formId,formFieldName) {
  console.log(formId + " " + formFieldName); // logs: [object HTMLFormElement] [object HTMLTextAreaElement]
}
```

I'm expecting `string string` instead.

Comment: @MisterJojo - Sorry, trying to keep it simple. The post is updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you concatenate the variables into the `onclick` attribute, they will be treated as variables because they're not quoted. So you get

```
toggleHideField(hi, bye);
```

You want

```
toggleHideField('hi', 'bye');
```

But rather than concatenating strings, you should use `addEventListener` with a closure:

```
elCheckbox.addEventListener('click', function() { 
  toggleHideField(myFormId, mhyInputName); 
});
```